# case-insensitive regular expression in a Google form: is it allowed?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I am using GAS to set some restriction to the string i receive from a textItem added to a form

initialy i have wrote it like that:

```
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm(); 
var textItem = form.addTextItem().setTitle('put some integer 
followed by A, B or C');
var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
.setHelpText('wrongPattern')
.requireTextContainsPattern(/(\d+)(a|b|c)/i)
.build();
textItem.setValidation(textValidation);
```

The idea was to get an integer followed by a,b or c and be case-insensitive.
It does not work and if i check the form editor i see that :[look at the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGGCY.png)

just changing the pattern,I make it do the drill but with something I don't feel great about

```
 .requireTextContainsPattern('(\\d+)(a|A|b|B|c|C)')
```

witch give in the form editor: [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7r7e.png)

My question is Why does it work ?
Witch rules to follow using:requireTextContainsPattern()?
how to do a case-insensitive pattern ?

Thank to  Wiktor Stribiżew here is an other brick added to the questionement.
If i use

```
.requireTextContainsPattern('(?i)\\d+[abc]')
```

the editor accept the regular expression as correct,but when you try to submit the form, the answer is not submitted, the button 'SUBMIT' become grey and nothing happen.

Comment: It looks as if regex literal notation is not supported here, hence you sould use a string pattern. Try `.requireTextContainsPattern('(?i)\\d+[abc]')`

Comment: the editor accept the regex but the response can't be submitted, it kind of freeze and you need to relaod

Comment: [tag:re2] is supported.

Comment: if re2 is supported then why isn't it possible to set a case insensitive pattern?